# Send variable to PHP and retrieve specific rows from MySQL that match with variable

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Now I am working on making reservation application. Thus, I am trying to send the variable to PHP and extract the rows that match with variable that I sent. Specifically, sends the userBranch from Android studio to PHP, and extracts the rows where courseBranch has same value with userBranch. I use where to set the conditions, but it could not retrieve data.

Here is my PHP code (CourseList.php)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pwd, $db) or die('Unable to connect');
$courseBranch = $_GET["userBranch"]

if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
    echo "Failed to Connect to Database".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT courseID, courseTeacher, courseDay, courseTime, courseBranch  FROM COURSE WHERE courseBranch = '$courseBranch'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $flag[] = $row;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}
mysqli_close($con);                        
?>
```

And this is my Android studio code where Data is parsed

```
<?php
private int parseData(){
    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        courseTeacher.clear();
        courseDay.clear();
        courseTime.clear();
        courseTeacherParse.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i <ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = jo.getInt("courseID");
            String name = jo.getString("courseTeacher");
            String day = jo.getString("courseDay");
            String time = jo.getString("courseTime");
            String branch = jo.getString("courseBranch");

            course = new Course();
            course.setCourseTeacher(name);
            course.setCourseDay(day);
            course.setCourseTime(time);
            courseTeacher.add(name);
            courseDay.add(day);
            courseTime.add(time);
            courseBranch.add(branch);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
?>
```

And this is urladdress

```
<?php
    String urlAddress = "";
    try {
        urlAddress = "http://show981111.cafe24.com/CourseList.php?userBranch=" + URLEncoder.encode(userBranch, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about android but what i can see here is you are sending encoded `userBranch` by `URLEncoder.encode()` but you are not decoding it when you use it in your query. I don't know i am right or not it's just an observation.